# H2O R Variable Importance Truncated List

Tags: r, h2o, gbm

I have a data set with over 400 features that I am estimating with GBM  using H2O atop R. When I use the variable importance function (h2o.varimp) it only shows me the head and tail of the full ranked variable list. Is there a way to have the entire list displayed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not specific to variable importance, this is just how H2O displays H2O Frames in the R console.  If you want to view the whole frame, you could convert it to an R data.frame and then print it.

```
df <- as.data.frame(h2o.varimp(model))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

(summary) will show all stats with extraction from h2o.varimp. Then save the table of variable importance

```
mymodel <- summary(model)

write.table(mymodel, file = "mymodel.txt", sep = "\t", quote = FALSE, row.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am curious, is that command also how you would permanently store a model object for scoring new data (in H2O format) in the future?

Comment: @dj_ski_mask Check out `h2o.saveModel()` and `h2o.loadModel()` for binary models.  Those are the easiest to use, however for productionizing models, check out `h2o.download_pojo()` or `h2o.download_mojo()`. http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/pojo-quick-start.html